Can I switch from my spouse PPO plan to HSA plan
I am on my spouse PPO plan as dependent and he is filing taxes married and filed jointly with his name. Now I got new job where my employer is giving HSA account(employer contribution too!). Can my husband remove me as dependent from his insurance and can I opt for HSA account in mid of year? If yes, how to file taxes for this year? My husband insurance plan is good with all benefits but I want to go with HSA account just for save some tax amount.

Have you ran the numbers?  Is it advantageous for you to move off his PPO onto hour HSA?

Note that having separate insurance does not affect how you file taxes (Joint vs Separate). You can still file jointly even with different health plans.

Does your spouse have an FSA account? I think that's not allowed with your HSA.

Note given you are covered by HDHP (and nothing else) by Dec and will remain covered all next year you can use the last-month rule to increase your voluntary contributions -- and deduction -- for this year using the whole-year limit rather than the 6 or so months of actual eligibility. (If necessary you have until next April 15 to depostit these contributions.) The employer probably won't increase their contribution beyond the months actually employed and covered, though.


Now I got new job where my employer is giving HSA account(employer
contribution too!).

Because you are gaining coverage, that allows your spouse to change their coverage. You need to signup for the new coverage during their window (usually 30 days), and then provide proof to your spouses employer/HR/benefits person.
This qualifying life event allows you to totally restructure your families coverage. Be mindful of the windows where the changes on both ends have to be made. Sometimes the new coverage starts on day 1, other times the first day of the next month. You don't want to end-up with zero coverage, or double coverage.
Make sure you understand what proof you will need, and where it has to be sent.
For example my child's employer wouldn't let them signup for coverage mid-year until they had a letter from the old insurance company saying they were being dropped because they were turning 26.
Your situation is hard to find in the examples because most of the time people make mid-year changes because of marriage or having a child, or because one spouse loses their job. Gaining coverage is a valid reason.
